# Check if datetime string is in ISO 8601 format

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil, python-datetime

I like to parse datetime strings with `dateutil.parser.parse` module. It's simple. However I noticed in my code that I have to check if the object is indeed in 8601 (and aware).

My structure is:

```
if parse(datetime).tzinfo==None:
   #do something
else:
   #make it aware
   #do something
```

and I want to achieve something like:

```
if <IS-8601>:
   if parse(datetime).tzinfo==None:
      #do something
   else:
      #make it aware
      #do something
else:
   pass
```

If I have a 8601 like e.g. `2014-02-28T22:30:00+0200` parse utility does its job.

If I have however a `2014-03-20` string parse will add time on the object. That's not wrong, just unwanted: `2014-03-20 00:00:00`

---

So how can I check if an object is in 8601? And if in 8601, is it aware? I don't mind change to another datetime library.

Comment: U can use regular expression . `re.compile(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[ T]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}$')`

Comment: ISO 8601 can have timezone character at end, i.e. `Z` instead of offset and can also have milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it by **datetime** module and check for exception `ValueError` before processing by `dateutil.parser.parse` :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-03-20", '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 20, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-02-28T22:30:00+0200", '%Y-%m-%d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#134>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-02-28T22:30:00+0200", '%Y-%m-%d')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\_strptime.py", line 340, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: T22:30:00+0200
```

Comment: This parser can parse much more than ISO8601-compliant strings, so it's not a good way of validating ISO8601 compliance.